# jQuery placing AND/OR input boxes in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

Hey all I am trying to find the "sweet spot" so that this will work as I am needing it to.

Below is my current JS code that I am working with.

AND BOX code:

```
$("#ANDbtn").click(function() {
   if (numOR > numAND) {
       //Place AND box AFTER previous OR box
       $("#ANDArea_" + (numOR + 1)).after(html);
       console.log('if: ANDArea_' + numOR + ">" + numAND);
   } else if (numAND > numOR) {
       //Place AND box AFTER previous AND box
       $("#ANDArea_" + (numAND - 1)).after(html);
       console.log('else if: ANDArea_' + numAND + ">" + numOR);
   } else {
       //There is no AND box so lets add the first one
       $("#ANDORArea").after(html);
       console.log('else');
   }

   numAND++;
});
```

OR BOX code:

```
$("#ORbtn").click(function() {
   if (numAND > numOR) {
       //Place OR box AFTER previous AND box
       $("#ORArea_" + (numAND + 1)).after(html);
       console.log('if: ORArea_' + numAND + ">" + numOR);
   } else if (numOR > numAND) {
       //Place OR box AFTER previous OR box
       $("#ORArea_" + (numOR - 1)).after(html);
       console.log('else if: ORArea_' + numOR + ">" + numAND);
   } else {
       //There is no OR box so lets add the first one
       $("#ANDORArea").after(html);
       console.log('else');
   }

   numOR++;
});
```

Each time the user pushes the button **AND** it **adds 1** to the **variable numAND**. Likewise, when the user pushes the **OR** button it **adds a 1** to the **variable numOR**. **Both variables** start at **0**.

When the user pushes the **AND** button it places the **AND box** on the screen (which goes to the **else** in the logic above) and if the user pushes the **AND** button again it places the **AND** box **AFTER** the **previous AND box** (which goes to the **else if** in the logic above).

The same goes for the **OR box** as well. When the user pushes the **OR** button it places the **OR box** on the screen (which goes to the **else** in the logic above) and if the user pushes the **OR** button **again** it places the **OR** box **AFTER** the **previous OR box** (which goes to the **else if** in the logic above).

So all that works just fine. Where I am having the issue is when I hit the **AND button** an **AND box** shows up and then hit the **OR button** - it does *not* place the **OR box BELOW** the **AND box** and *vise versa*.

Here's a [FIDDLER](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq07ydek/1/) for you're viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `after` jQuery function to place some of the elements, which is sticking the elements after the `#ANDORArea` row instead of at the end of the table. I believe you want to `append` the elements to the end of the table. To do that you'd replace `$("#ANDORArea").after(html)` with something along the lines of `$("#ANDORAreaTableBody").append(html)` such that the elements are placed at the end of the table, below the other elements.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq07ydek/2/) to see it in action.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks forrestmid!